# Evaluate if series with exponential diverges or converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, divergent-series

The task is to evaluate for what values of $a \in \Bbb R_+$ does the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n \times n!}{n^n}$$
converge. I've already checked with the ratio test that it converges for $ a < e $ and diverges for $a > e$, but I can't seem to find the answer what happens for $a = e$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^n \times n!}{n^n}$$

What test should I apply?

Comment: Use the limit test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the Stirling formula, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^{n}}{e^{n}}
$$ one gets that, as $n \to \infty$,

> $$
> \frac{e^n \times n!}{n^n}\sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \to +\infty \neq0
> $$

and the initial series is **divergent**.

Comment: I haven't had the Stirling formula yet, but thank you very much anyway, I'll use it. Just what I was looking for!

Comment: @Voreny OK. You are welcome.